# How to declare and update variables in google closure templates(soy template)

Tags: google-closure-templates, soy-templates

Lets take 2 arrays **arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']** and **arr2 = ['1' , '2', '3']**. When passed these arrays as params to a soy template, I want to iterate as shown below and print an **index** that indicates total items iterated so far.

```
index: 0 //variable assigned to 0 by default
{foreach $i in $arr1}
    {foreach $j in $arr2}
       index = index + 1; //variable incremented by 1
       {$index} th item //print item index
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Since variable declared using **let** cannot be re-assigned to a new value, is there a way in templates to achieve the logic I have shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Within the block, you can use three special functions that only take the iterator as their argument:

- `isFirst($var)` returns `true` only on the first iteration.
- `isLast($var)` returns `true` only on the last iteration.
- **`index($var)` returns the current index in the list. List indices are 0-based.**

Then you can use `index($j)`:

```
{foreach $i in $arr1}
  {foreach $j in $arr2}
    {index($j)}
  {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Hope I could help ;)

Source: https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/commands#foreach